# iframe height issue when content changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have one main page which includes side menus & `iframe`. When user click on any menu, It opens new page in `iframe`. Side menus will be as it is. Now, I am getting height issue when any page content changes.
**My code :**

```
<html>
<body>
      <div id="menu">
           // Menus...
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <iframe id="frameData" width="100%" style="height:100%">
             // New Page Content which will open...
         </iframe>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, is there any way to set `content` or `frameData` height from New `HTML` Page. Then, It will solve my problem.
Or any better proper solution for this ?

Comment: how about adding min-height and max-height to your div or iFrame?

Comment: @TechGirl, na, it wont solve problem.